# Ember.js with Twitter cards and Facebook OG

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ember.js, twitter-card

I'm have cards and og meta tags in my emberjs app, but when i check twitter/facebook debugging tools, they retrieved home page data. Any ideas what could be the problem?

BTW, I'm using NGINX mod_rewrite, and history url if thats any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve these from the server, Facebook cannot crawl javascript generated DOM.

Comment: But I'm using `api.domain.com` for api, and `domain.com` my webapp. When posting this mean i'll have to share link using `api.domain.com`. How can I fix that?